# Firebase security rules based on currently existing values

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a rule in my firebase DB that dis-allows a user to update a posts likes value if it doesn't already exists in their fanned data. Consider this file structure.

[image]

Notice how there is a full dictionary of values. Given conditions in my app, users have the ability to write to the likes value in this dictionary. In the event that this dictionary of data **Does not already exist**, I want to prevent users from writing to the likes value so this doesn't happen.

[image]

This is the security rule I have currently in place but I am not sure how I can solve this problem.

[image]

I have already looked at the documentation and watched David East's video on securing your Firebase DB but I am still lost.

Comment: can you post the code instead of images?

Comment: For the database structure, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).